# In Excel, how do I join portions from different dynamic arrays into one new dynamic array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

In Excel (but without the use of VB) how do I join some columns from one dynamic array to columns from another such that result is also a dynamic array?

Here's a very simple example. Suppose I have two 2-column dynamic arrays of equal length. The first is in A1:B5, and the second is in D2:E6. I would like to create a new, third dynamic array in G3:H7 such that G3:G7 contains whatever is in A1:A5, and H3:H7 contains whatever is in E2:E6. Here is an illustration.

```
 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
—|———+———+———+———+———+———+———+———|
1| a | 1 |   |   |.  |   |   |   |
2| b | 3 |   | f | 0 |   |   |   |
3| c | 5 |   | g | 2 |   | a | 0 |
4| d | 7 |   | h | 4 |   | b | 2 |
5| e | 9 |   | i | 6 |   | c | 4 |
6|   |   |   | j | 8 |   | d | 6 |
7|   |   |   |   |   |   | e | 8 |
—————————————————————————————————-
```

Now I already know I can create a third array using the following formulae:

```
G3 = INDEX(A1#,0,1)
H3 = INDEX(D2#,0,2)
```

However, that gives me a result in the form of two 1-column dynamic arrays, whereas I'd like it to be a single 2-column dynamic array.

At the moment, my approach is to treat G3:G7 as a helper array, and I then create my desired final dynamic version with something like this:

```
J3 = OFFSET(G3,0,0,ROWS(A3#),2)
```

And I could probably even cobble together some monstrosity that got rid of the need for the helper. But this is such a common form of operation that I was hoping there might be a more elegant, "canonical" method, perhaps drawing on the new dynamic array functions themselves.

Can anyone suggest one? (Again, no Visual Basic please.)

Comment: There is a Function currently in the Beta Channel Called VSTACK() that would do this.

Comment: Thanks. That looks like _exactly_ what I'm after! (I presume you meant HSTACK for my example.) if you elevate your comment to an answer, I can mark it.

Comment: Yup I missread, I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current functions in Office 365 we can use CHOOSE with a horizontal array:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},INDEX(A1#,0,1),INDEX(D2#,0,2))
```

This will stack the two vertical arrays side by side

[image]

In time when the Current Beta channel items are released to the normal user we can use VSTACK:

```
=HSTACK(INDEX(A1#,0,1),INDEX(D2#,0,2))
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Your CHOOSE illustration is an example of the kind of "monstrosity" I'm trying to avoid.  But the new function you mention is exactly what I'm looking for.